# Moving Columns for mobile users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Bootstrap MVC and have a 3 column layout for the index page for a internal blog. Small left hand column which shows pics, blogs in the middle and useful widget in the small right column.

When you view the site on a mobile device it all moves as it should but I would like the left column to move after the main blog column only for a mobile device. Is this possible I found the push and pull commands but it dosnt do it for just mobiles?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is either use the default media queries in your own css files. These are the ones that bootstrap uses:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

or depending on your layout you may want different break points. You would just either use id's for those columns or add classes to get the behavior that you want.

Hope it helps!